# Javascript: enable/disable button with mouseover/mouseout

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

This should be pretty straightforward:

`<input type="button" name="test" id="test" value="roll over me"  onmouseover="this.disabled=true;" onmouseout="this.disabled=false;">`

If I place the mouse cursor over this button, it gets disabled..yay!
But now when I move the cursor out, it doesn't get enabled...boo.

I understand the concept of disabling it means you can't do anything with it.  But how do you get it to be enabled with a mouse out?  Is it possible?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the mouseout to `disabled = ''` instead.

```
<input type="button" name="test" id="test" value="roll over me" onmouseover="this.disabled=true;" onmouseout="this.disabled='';">
```

The disabled property only looks to see if it's there at all.  You can set disabled='anything' and it will be disabled.  It used to be that you only needed the keyword `disabled` in your attributes but for valid XHTML you need to set every attribute equal to something.

**EDIT:**
I played around with this a little bit and added some padding to the `SPAN` tag and it allows the events to work properly.  Without padding, it's not trapping the events because the input button is disabled.  I just made the background red so it was easy to see the area the `SPAN` used up.

```
<span style="padding: 8px; background: red;"  onmouseout="this.firstChild.disabled='';"><input type="button" name="test" id="test" value="roll over me" onmouseover="this.disabled=true;"></span>
```

Comment: @Shawn:  Thanks for that, but unfortunately, that doesn't work either :(

Comment: As others have said, the events won't fire once it is disabled.  You can wrap it in a span tag, but that acts a little funky because of the way events bubble up. Are you using any javascript frameworks like MooTools or jQuery?

Comment: @Shawn: Unfortunately, no.  yeah it would have been nicer, cleaner, and unobtrusive had I had a framework, which is why I posted this, the old fashioned way (a.k.a. old skool). I'll give your code a try.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: That worked for me in IE8, FF2 and Chrome.  It may work better if you use a CSS styled link button instead of an input button if you can do that.

Answer (score 3):

## Divs to the Rescue!

Too bad no one has really answered this question. It is possible to do*.

```
<div style="display: inline-block; position: relative">
<input type="button" id="button" disabled="disabled">
<div id="buttonMouseCatcher" style="position:absolute; z-index: 1;
  top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;">
</div>
```

Then:

- Put a mouse-over handler on buttonMouseCatcher that:

  - changes it's z-index to -1 and
  - enables the button.
- Put a mouse-out handler on button that:

  - changes the z-index of buttonMouseCatcher back to 1 and
  - disables the button.

Answer (score 1):

Disabled form elements don't fire mouse events, by the spec.

What I use as a workaround is to simulate the disabled behavior with a 'disabled' class and event handles associate with it. Works well for buttons, but I suppose it wouldn't for text inputs and checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

you could have an outer element that surrounds it and have an onmouseover for that outer element that enables the inner element.

Comment: oh and i removed the onmouseout attribute from the button.

Comment: '<span onmouseout="document.getElementById('test').disabled='';">' '<input type="button" name="test" id="test" value="roll over me"' 'onmouseover="this.disabled=true;">'
'</span>'

Still only works in IE.