# How to make a button clickabled when hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This question is going to sound strange to many of you. I need a button where it can't be triggered by a click. That means it won't do an action. Like if the form attribute `action` is set to something like `next.html` the click won't cause it to go to the next page.

And when the user hovers over the button, it can go to the next site. The reason why I am doing this is because a bot can submit data without **hovering over the button**. I am hoping this will prevent bots from submitting anything into my site.

I don't really have any code, but is there any way to do this in Javascript/jQuery?

If this confusing please ask more questions in the comments and I will try to answer to the best of my capabilities.

Comment: You mean to submit a form on hover instead of click?

Comment: @showdev No. I need it where the action is available when the user hovers over the button.

Comment: Skip every thought of stopping bots client side, stop them server side. You should always, always, always validate forms server side

Comment: @LGSon Oh, really?

Comment: A bot might post directly to your server-side script, avoiding your form altogether. I have, however, had some success with [honey pots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227376/better-honeypot-implementation-form-anti-spam).

Comment: @showdev If that helps, then I'll do that way.

Comment: You will thank us later :)

Comment: @LGSon Thanks for your help!

Comment: @showdev Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I am not sure how effective this technique would be at blocking bots. If you still want to give it a go, I'd do something like this:

HTML:

```
<form class="form" action="1.php" type="post">
  <input type="text">
  <input class="submitbutton" type="submit">
</form>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
var $form = $('.form'),
    $btn = $('.submitbutton');

// Disable submit button on page load
$btn.prop('disabled',true);

// Reactivate submit button on form hover
$form.hover(
  function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $btn.prop('disabled',false);
  }, function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $btn.prop('disabled',true);
  }
);
```

I put together [an example at JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/z5do7v66/1/)

Comment: @BoeNoe **Bad** for multiple reasons. If if a user uses the TAB key to move trough the form Action elements. Also will not work for bots. **A bot does not needs JS at all.** and will still submit your form!! Here you're just messing with UX.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Ok, fine. I get your point. I thought this would work for some reason.

Comment: I have to agree with @RokoC.Buljan. This will probably cause more problems for your users than it will actually block bots from submitting your form. Now as you're using javascript anyways, I guess your best bet would be to implement some sort of CAPTCHA script :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Bots search for the `<form>` element
2. Bots query for the form's `action` value

Bots won't follow your form `action` if there's no form in your page. If that might sound strange:

- Create your entire form using JS (**No form? No bots.**)

Either way (specially if you care about noJS visitors) you need to validate your form

1. on server side (that's what matter the most)
2. on client side (JavaScript; notify your users if they forgot to fill something - typos)

---

Here you can find [an approach example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34623588/383904)

---

Why your `hover` approach/intent is bad:

- You'll be only messing with UI creating a bad UX. Nothing more.
- The form is already there on the page revealing all what a bot needs.
- The bot does not need any *button* to submit your form.
- Some users might use the TAB key to focus the SUBMIT button - so there's no ***hover*** involved whatsoever, just a poor form that does not work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

In general, clicking the button should submit the form.  If you want to force the issue, I think you should try to disable the button first.

```
<span style="padding: 8px; background: red;"  onmouseout="this.firstChild.disabled='';"><input type="button" name="test" id="test" value="roll over me" onmouseover="this.disabled=true;"></span>
```

as provided in the answer here:

[Javascript: enable/disable button with mouseover/mouseout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744138/javascript-enable-disable-button-with-mouseover-mouseout)

Comment: But I don't want to disable the button. I just want it to be able to do nothin until a button is hovered over.

Comment: It seems that disabling the button would make it do nothing. No?

Comment: @showdev  I want it where the `action` attribute is not set until the user hovers over the form.

Comment: The answer you accepted is essentially enabling and disabling the button.  Glad you found an acceptable to you.

Answer (score -1):

it seems your question is navigating to another page without clicking a button.

```
         <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <button onmouseover="go()"  id="button">hii</button>
                <script>
                    var anchor=document.createElement("a");
                    var button=document.getElementById("button");
                    anchor.href="alarm2.html";
                    function go()
                    {
                        button.onmouseover= anchor.click();

                    }
                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply trigger `window.location.href='alarm2.html'` rather than simulating a click on a generated anchor element? That being said, I don't really see how this solution answers the question asked by BoeNoe.